# Boundary of bounded convex planar set is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I'm trying to prove that the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of any non-empty bounded convex planar set $\Omega$  is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

My current ideas are as follows:

- W.L.O.G assume that $0$ is in the interior of $\Omega$. Any half-line emanating from $0$ intersects $\partial \Omega$ at precisely one point. I have shown that the projection
  $\displaystyle \pi : \partial \Omega \to S^{1} : x\mapsto \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}$ is well-defined, continuous and bijective.
- My issue arises with the inverse map $\displaystyle \pi^{-1}: S^1 \to \partial\Omega:x'\mapsto f(x')x'$ where $f(x) = \sup\lbrace t> 0 \mid tx'\in\Omega\rbrace$. $\pi^{-1}$ is continuous provided that $f:S^{1} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is continuous.

Note that here I am setting $S^1 = \lbrace (x,y) \mid x^{2}+y^{2} = 1\rbrace$ and am endowing it with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

My approach thus far has been to suppose that $f$ isn't continuous and then showing that $\Omega$ is not convex. And following an argument like:

*If $f$ is not continuous at $x$ then $\exists \delta >0$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $y_{n}\in B(x;\frac{1}{n})$ such that $|f(y_{n})-f(x)| \geq \delta$. Then we have that the line $[f(y_{n}),f(y_{n+1})]$ is contained in $\overline{\Omega}$. This implies that...*

Am I on to the right thing? I can't seem to reach the contradiction I want.

*Remark.* It may be a rather silly way of doing it but showing that this $f$ is continuous would greatly help me with some other results so I do hope this is the case!

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: There's a theorem that if $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection, $X$ is compact, and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ is continuous.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for signposting me to this theorem! It does the trick as then $\pi^{-1}$ is continuous and thus my $f : S^{1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is necessarily (uniformly) continuous. Many thanks once again.